# Holiday Calendar implementation using drools rules

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am very new and learning drools. 
I am trying to create rule-based holiday calendar. There are set of rules implemented which determines based on date it is holiday or business day

I created rule file and class which seems to be working

Rule file

```
//created on: Dec 30, 2017
//list any import classes here.
import com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.model.CheckDay;
import java.util.*;


//declare any global variables here


rule "Weekend1_saturday"

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay($dayofWeek : dayofWeek == 7)
    then
        //actions
         System.out.println("Weekend1_saturday");
        modify($checkday) {
           setWeekend1(true)
         }; 
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Weekend2_sunday"

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay($dayofWeek : dayofWeek == 1)
    then
        //actions
        System.out.println("Weekend1_sunday");
        modify($checkday) {
           setWeekend2(true)
         };

end

rule "Holiday_newyear_day"

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay($month : month == 1, $dayofMonth : dayofMonth == 1)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_newyear_day");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end


rule "Holiday_MartinLutherKingBirthday."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 1,  dayofWeek == 2, dayofWeekinMonth == 3)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_MartinLutherKingBirthday.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_WashingtonBirthday_PresidentsDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 2,  dayofWeek == 2, dayofWeekinMonth == 3)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_WashingtonBirthday_PresidentsDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_MemorialDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 5,  dayofWeek == 2, dayofMonth > (31 - 7))
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_MemorialDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_IndependenceDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 7, dayofMonth == 4)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_IndependenceDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_LaborDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 9,  dayofWeek == 2, dayofWeekinMonth == 1)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_LaborDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_ColumbusDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 10,  dayofWeek == 2, dayofWeekinMonth == 2)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_ColumbusDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end


rule "Holiday_VeteransDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 11, dayofMonth == 11)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_VeteransDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_ThanksGivingDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 11, dayofWeek == 5, dayofWeekinMonth == 4)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_ThanksGivingDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_ChristmasDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 12, dayofMonth == 25)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_ChristmasDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end
```

java Class File

```
package com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.model;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import lombok.Data;

public @Data class CheckDay {


private int dayofWeek;
  private int month;
  private int dayofMonth;
  private int dayofWeekinMonth;
  private int year;
  public boolean isWeekend1; // Weekend 1 = Saturday
  public boolean isWeekend2; // Weekend 1 = Sunday
  public boolean isHoliday;
  private Date currentday;
  private Date nextday;
  private Date previousday;
  private Calendar cal;

  public CheckDay(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, dayOfMonth);
    this.year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    this.month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    this.dayofMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    this.dayofWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    this.dayofWeekinMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
    this.currentday = cal.getTime();
    this.setNextday();
    this.setPreviousday();
  }

  public void setPreviousday() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(this.currentday);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    this.previousday = c.getTime();
  }


  public void setNextday() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(this.currentday);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    this.nextday = c.getTime();
  }
}
```

but now I want to implement 2 rules

**if nextdate is holiday and nextdate is weekend1 then isholiday=true**

**if previousdate is a holiday and previousdate is weekend2 then isholiday=true**

I added nextday and previousday properties to CheckDay class but I am not able to figure out a way to implement these 2 rules

I need advice from drool expert on how to implement these rule or how to solve this problem using drool.

Note: I am already know how to solve this without using drools so I am not looking for that answer. My intent is not to solve holidaycalendar questions but I want to understand can this type of question be solved using drool?

other classes

```
package com.intlsys.holidaycalendar;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.model.CheckDay;
import com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.service.HolidayCalculator;
import com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.service.HolidayCalculatorImpl;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HolidaycalendarApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HolidaycalendarApplication.class, args);

    ApplicationContext context =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HolidayCalendarCalculation.class);

    HolidayCalculator holidayCalculatorService =
            (HolidayCalculator) context.getBean(HolidayCalculatorImpl.class);

    CheckDay day = new CheckDay(2018, 12, 25);
    boolean isbusinessday = holidayCalculatorService.isbusinessday(day);

    System.out.println("isbusinessday: " + isbusinessday);

  }
}
```

and

```
package com.intlsys.holidaycalendar;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieBuilder;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieFileSystem;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieModule;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.service")
public class HolidayCalendarCalculation {
    public static final String drlFile = "HOLIDAY_RULES.drl";


    @Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(drlFile));
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kieBuilder.buildAll();
        KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();

        return kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());

    }
}
```

service class

```
package com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.service;

import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.model.CheckDay;

@Service
public class HolidayCalculatorImpl implements HolidayCalculator {

    @Autowired
    private KieContainer kContainer;

  @Override
  public boolean isbusinessday(CheckDay day) {

      KieSession kieSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
      kieSession.insert(day);
      kieSession.fireAllRules();
      kieSession.dispose();
      return day.isHoliday()? false: true;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve problem,but there should be better way

The way I solved In holidaycalculation service I populate the setNextdayweekend1Holiday and setPreviousdayWeekend2Holiday 
and then I added two rules Weekend1_saturday and Weekend2_sunday

Rule file

```
//created on: Dec 30, 2017
//list any import classes here.
import com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.model.CheckDay;
import java.util.*;


//declare any global variables here


rule "Weekend1_saturday"

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay($dayofWeek : dayofWeek == 7)
    then
        //actions
         System.out.println("Weekend1_saturday");
        modify($checkday) {
           setWeekend1(true)
         }; 
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Weekend2_sunday"

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay($dayofWeek : dayofWeek == 1)
    then
        //actions
        System.out.println("Weekend1_sunday");
        modify($checkday) {
           setWeekend2(true)
         };

end

rule "Holiday_newyear_day"

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay($month : month == 1, $dayofMonth : dayofMonth == 1)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_newyear_day");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end


rule "Holiday_MartinLutherKingBirthday."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 1,  dayofWeek == 2, dayofWeekinMonth == 3)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_MartinLutherKingBirthday.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_WashingtonBirthday_PresidentsDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 2,  dayofWeek == 2, dayofWeekinMonth == 3)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_WashingtonBirthday_PresidentsDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_MemorialDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 5,  dayofWeek == 2, dayofMonth > (31 - 7))
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_MemorialDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_IndependenceDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 7, dayofMonth == 4)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_IndependenceDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_LaborDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 9,  dayofWeek == 2, dayofWeekinMonth == 1)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_LaborDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_ColumbusDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 10,  dayofWeek == 2, dayofWeekinMonth == 2)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_ColumbusDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end


rule "Holiday_VeteransDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 11, dayofMonth == 11)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_VeteransDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_ThanksGivingDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 11, dayofWeek == 5, dayofWeekinMonth == 4)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_ThanksGivingDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_ChristmasDay."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(month == 12, dayofMonth == 25)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_ChristmasDay.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end


rule "Holiday_Nextdayweekend1Holiday."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(nextdayweekend1Holiday == true)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_Nextdayweekend1Holiday.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end

rule "Holiday_Previousdayweekend2Holiday."

    when
        //conditions
        $checkday : CheckDay(previousdayWeekend2Holiday == true)
    then
            System.out.println("Holiday_Previousdayweekend2Holiday.");
        //actions
        modify($checkday) {
           setHoliday(true)
         };
end
```

Class file

```
package com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.service;

import java.util.Calendar;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.model.CheckDay;

@Service
public class HolidayCalculatorImpl implements HolidayCalculator {

  @Autowired private KieContainer kContainer;

  @Override
  public boolean isbusinessday(CheckDay day) {

    KieSession kieSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();

    //check if next day is holiday and saturday
    cal1.setTime(day.getNextday());
    CheckDay nextday =
        new CheckDay(
            cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    kieSession.insert(nextday);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
    if (nextday.isHoliday == true && nextday.isWeekend1 == true)
      day.setNextdayweekend1Holiday(true);

    // check if previous day is holiday and sunday
    cal1.setTime(day.getPreviousday());
    CheckDay previousday =
        new CheckDay(
            cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    kieSession.insert(previousday);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
    if (previousday.isHoliday == true && previousday.isWeekend2 == true)
      day.setPreviousdayWeekend2Holiday(true);

    kieSession.insert(day);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
    kieSession.dispose();
    return day.isHoliday() ? false : true;
  }
}
```

Service class

```
package com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.service;

import java.util.Calendar;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.intlsys.holidaycalendar.model.CheckDay;

@Service
public class HolidayCalculatorImpl implements HolidayCalculator {

  @Autowired private KieContainer kContainer;

  @Override
  public boolean isbusinessday(CheckDay day) {

    KieSession kieSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();

    //check if next day is holiday and saturday
    cal1.setTime(day.getNextday());
    CheckDay nextday =
        new CheckDay(
            cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    kieSession.insert(nextday);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
    if (nextday.isHoliday == true && nextday.isWeekend1 == true)
      day.setNextdayweekend1Holiday(true);

    // check if previous day is holiday and sunday
    cal1.setTime(day.getPreviousday());
    CheckDay previousday =
        new CheckDay(
            cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    kieSession.insert(previousday);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
    if (previousday.isHoliday == true && previousday.isWeekend2 == true)
      day.setPreviousdayWeekend2Holiday(true);

    kieSession.insert(day);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
    kieSession.dispose();
    return day.isHoliday() ? false : true;
  }
}
```